# Copy Data from Sheet to another based on drop-down value

Tags: excel, vba

I have several sheets in one workbook. I want to copy-paste the data (entire content) from different sheets to sheet 1 (let's say from B6) based on the drop-down value in 'A2' in Sheet 1. Drop-down consists of names of all the other sheets. So, if I select Sheet 2 in drop-down, it should copy entire content from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1, starting from B6.

Here is the macro, I created for it. But it's not working. Can you help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

```
Sub Button21_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim criteria As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Set values for your variables.
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    criteria = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    
Dim TT As ListObject

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    
        With Sheets(i)
            For Each TT In Sheets(i).ListObjects
                If TT.Name = criteria Then TT.Range.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6:Q22").PasteSpecial: Exit Sub
                        
            Next
        End With
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: It's not working! :(

Comment: I can't figure out what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that does work.

```
Sub Button21_Click()

    Dim Wb          As Workbook
    Dim Criteria    As String
    Dim i           As Integer                  ' loop counter: Sheets
    Dim Tbl         As ListObject               ' loop object
    
    'Set values for your variables.
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Criteria = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To Wb.Sheets.Count                ' { "Shees(1)" is in the ActiveWorkbook
                                                ' { which may be different from Wb
        For Each Tbl In Wb.Sheets(i).ListObjects
            If Tbl.Name = Criteria Then
                Tbl.Range.Copy
                Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").PasteSpecial
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next Tbl
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

1. You should declare ***all*** variables, not only objects. And it's better to prepare your tools before starting on the job, i.e. declare variables before writing code that uses them.
2. What's the point of declaring `Set Wb = ThisWorkbook` if you use the default workbook (= ActiveWorkbook) thereafter?
3. `PasteSpecial` needs its own line. The construct you used would deliver the argument for the `Copy` object's `Destination` property. The latter is an address and can't include the `PasteSpecial` method.
4. It's enough to specify the first cell to paste to.

Note that the `ListObject`'s Range comprises of the entire table. Use the `DataBodyRange` to specify only data (without headers and totals).

Comment: Also, declare wb as Dim wb As ThisWorkbook if set to ThisWorkbook. And they only need to consider Worksheets collection.